# Observer for Magento Attribute Set Save After, Delete

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I need an Observer called when an **Attribute Set** is **Saved** & **Deleted**. I can't seem to find the right event name for it.

After some digging, I figured out that the Model I need to tap into is http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Eav/Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Set.html

Since it implements the `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract` class, it should allow me access to the save_after, delete_after event names. But I can't seem to figure out the syntax for defining the observer for it.

I tried `eav_attribute_set_save_after`, `model_eav_attribute_set_save_after`, `attribute_set_save_after` but they don't seem to work.

What's the right event name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you had dug just a little bit more, you would have seen that these "generic" model events are formed like this :

```
Mage::dispatchEvent($this->_eventPrefix.'_save_after', $this->_getEventData());
```

Now if you look at the `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Set` class you see the eventPrefix attribute defined as :

```
protected $_eventPrefix = 'eav_entity_attribute_set';
```

So your event will be :

```
eav_entity_attribute_set_save_after
```

Note that this protected attribute needs to be defined for each Model you want to access generic events (some magento models doesn't have this attribute setted by default, just be aware of it... you might have to add it yourself someday)